# reverse proxy caching dynamic content with login session

Tags: nginx, openresty

Is it possible to caching reverse proxy with login user ?
I’m trying to figure out how to do it on openresty ,
Now the status is “BYPASS” because im bypassing the cookie session.

I can make it “HIT” by not bypassing the cookie , but it doesn’t allow me to login the site,

here is my recent configuration that shown "BYPASS"

```
  proxy_cache_path  /tmp/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my-cache:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
```

proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx;

```
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
server {

location / {
    set_by_lua $no_cache '
    if ngx.var.cookie_COOKIE == "" or ngx.var.cookie_COOKIE == nil then
    return 1
    end
    return ""
    ';
    proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_cache my-cache;
    proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
    proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    proxy_cache_min_uses 3;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502
                          http_503 http_504;
    proxy_cache_background_update on;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    proxy_cache_key "$no_cache$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$mobile_request";
```

The question is
Is it possible to make it “HIT” and still allowed to login to the site ?

Is it possible to make it “HIT” and still allowed to login to the site ?